# .charAt() not working inside ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use .charAt() inside an ajax call 
.charAt is coming in autoComplete outside $.each function, but inside it, that function is not coming !!

```
 function success2(res) {
                var somevar;
                firstchar=somevar.charAt(0); //here its working
      $.each(res, function (i, data) {

               firstLetter= data.strContent.charAt(0); // not working here
```

Comment: try alerting the value `data.strContent`

Comment: ya its having data, i used debugger
problem is .charAt is not coming in intellisense there

Comment: @vignesh, show the "data"

Comment: How could the `somevar.charAt(0)` with the comment "here its working" actually work when `somevar` is `undefined`? Anyway, regarding the part in the `$.each()` loop, please try `console.log(res)` and/or `console.log(data)` and show us the results, because we can't guess what your `res` structure is - if `data` doesn't have a `strContent` property, or if that property isn't, in fact, a string then `.charAt()` won't work on it.

Comment: How does your `res` looks like?

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn it worked after i use String(data.strContent).charAt(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with

```
data.strContent
```

It worked after using `String()`

```
String(data.strContent).charAt(0)
```

worked

Comment: Yes, you can use .toString() as well